# DynamicMethod.Invoke or DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate+Invoke - which is faster?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, dynamicmethod, dynamic-method

Which of the following gives better performance:

```
DynamicMethod dm = ....
..
//create IL for 'dm'
//store 'dm' for later use
..
..
later
..
..
dm.Invoke(..);
```

OR

```
DynamicMethod dm;
Delegate del = dm.CreateDelegate()
// store 'del' for later use
..
..
later
..
..
del(..);
```

**Note that typically 10s or 100s of different DynamicMethods will be created and each DynamicMethod (via hashtable of stored 'dm's or 'del's) will be called multiple times.**

Comment: Should be pretty straightforward to benchmark...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just creating 'throw away' methods (iow not using them again), it does not matter.

If you however reuse them, the second option will be significantly faster.

**Update:**

The first option uses reflection only (`RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(...)`). I will assume that internally, the `DynamicMethod` will be compiled at some stage too, which will incur some additional overhead on the first call and possibly additional calls.

The second option, the `DynamicMethod` is explicitly compiled to a known delegate type. As everyone should know, 'direct' delegate calls are almost as fast as a 'direct' method call.

**Opinion:**

Always use the second option, even when just using them once. You will have some compile time benefits additionally to the massive performance increase.

Comment: I need to call them repeatedly.